# Passing pointer from unmanaged to managed code

Tags: c#, c++

I have a simple C++ class that has two different methods for passing a pointer-to-struct:

Test.h:

```
struct TestStruct
{   
    int first;
    float second;
};

class TestWCM
{
public:
    TestWCM();
    ~TestWCM();

    TestStruct* GetTestStruct();
    void GetTestStruct(TestStruct* testStructOut);
private:
    TestStruct* testStruct;
};
```

Test.cpp:

```
#include "Test.h"

TestWCM::TestWCM()
{
    testStruct = new TestStruct();

    testStruct->first = 42;
    testStruct->second = 24.4;
}

TestWCM::~TestWCM()
{
    delete testStruct;
}

TestStruct* TestWCM::GetTestStruct()
{

    return testStruct;
}

void TestWCM::GetTestStruct(TestStruct* testStructOut)
{
    testStructOut = testStruct;
}
```

This class is being used by a Visual C++ Class Library project:

WCM_Wrapper.h:

```
#include "C:\Test.h"
#include "C:\Test.cpp"

using namespace System;

namespace WCM_Wrapper_Lib {

    public value struct TestThis
    {
        int first;
        float second;
    };

    public ref class TestWrapper
    {
    public:
        TestWrapper();
        ~TestWrapper();

        TestThis GetTestStruct();
    private:
        TestWCM* test;
    };
}
```

WCM_Wrapper.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "WCM_Wrapper_Lib.h"

WCM_Wrapper_Lib::TestWrapper::TestWrapper()
{
    test = new TestWCM();
}

WCM_Wrapper_Lib::TestWrapper::~TestWrapper()
{
    delete test;
}

WCM_Wrapper_Lib::TestThis
WCM_Wrapper_Lib::TestWrapper::GetTestStruct()
{
    TestStruct* testStruct = test->GetTestStruct();

    TestThis testThis;

    testThis.first = testStruct->first;
    testThis.second = testStruct->second;


    // This causes a null-pointer exception:
    // TestStruct* testStructTwo;
    // test->GetTestStruct(testStructTwo);
    // int first = testStructTwo->first;

    return testThis;
}
```

I can call the unmanaged C++ code from a C# Windows forms project and it works fine, but if I use the second method of the C++ class (see commented code) I get an exception.

why is it allowed to use a pointer as a return value but not when it has been passed as a parameter?

Comment: Why is this tagged as C#?

Comment: You should use  void GetTestStruct(TestStruct*& testStructOut); instead of void GetTestStruct(TestStruct* testStructOut);

Comment: @Codor I'm calling this wrapper from a C# application, I thought it might be relevant.

Comment: @Amadeusz I tried it and it worked, but I don't understand why. I would prefer using the C++ code as-is. Is it not possible to use the original method? Thanks!

Comment: You first have to write valid native C++ code before you can consider wrapping it.  And it is not valid at all, the exception is the reminder.  The declaration must be `TestStruct testStructTwo;`, the call must be `test->GetTestStruct(&testStructTwo);` and the function itself is completely broken as well, it needs to be  `*testStructOut = *testStruct;`  Ask for help from a more experienced team member, you need a code review.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks

Comment: @Q-bertsuit You are passing pointer by value (in function you are getting a copy) and you have to pass it by refference in order to change its value.